# iOS - Previous screen flashing when coming from background

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiapplicationdelegate

This is my situation:  I push a ViewController that is in landscape mode, then go to the home screen.  When I go back in the app, the previous views in the back stack flash for just a moment before going to my ViewController.  This doesn't happen for portrait ViewControllers.

Has anyone seen this before or know of a workaround?  Thanks!

For the record, I am simply pushing the ViewController via:

```
self.navigationController!.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true);
```

and then forcing the view into landscape mode, not sure if that's relevant.

Comment: put some code would be better. Such as how you push the viewcontroller, or viewwillappear method.

Comment: I understand it is always better to post code, but I am not pushing the viewcontroller in any unique way.

The only thing I am doing differently in the viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear for this view is forcing landscape

Comment: I've had something similar to this happen before when I hadn't set a background color for the viewcontrollers view - have you set a color? If not could you try that and tell me if it prevent the other viewcontroller's views from appearing?

Comment: Release the view then push the new one.

Comment: @williamb thank you for responding!  That unfortunately did not fix the issue tho

Comment: @John thanks for the suggestion. This view does need a back stack bcuz it has a back button but maybe I can release some previous views.

Comment: Sure thing, or just hide the view or set the backgroundColor to black

Comment: You can try presenting your view controller quickly without loading its contents, then load the content after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What solved this problem for me was calling

```
window?.makeKeyAndVisible();
```

in the AppDelegate file

Comment: Also helped with flashing views during app state restoration 5 years after the answer )